# Intellij Flutter adding prefix to imports

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

I have installed the latest version of IntelliJ with the latest version of the flutter plugin. But when I trigger the code completion (Command + Space) for something like `List`, I see this being added to the imports

`import 'dart:core' as prefix0;`

and my `List` becomes

`prefix0.List`

Anything I can do to avoid this annoying bug?

---

**Flutter doctor:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/sravindran/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 months ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sravindran/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/sravindran/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 33.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 35.3.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.7141.49

[✓] VS Code (version 1.30.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.25.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I think you have some miss-configuration. There's no need to import ```dart:core``` for ```List```. Can you post the ```flutter doctor``` output ?

Comment: I ran flutter doctor from Tools > Flutter > Flutter Doctor. This is the output - https://pastebin.com/JYs2Yc1D

Comment: I've experienced the same issue from the beta channel (running Flutter v. 1.5.4-hotfix.2) and IntelliJ 2019.1.1

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed problem about this. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36890

I guess this is an error in the SDK when certain actions are performed in sequence. For me, reset the computer and the visual Studio Code worked to solve the import problem.